# How many people have X and Y?

Tags: probability

I have a problem for which I know the answer, but have no idea why it works.

Of 40 people, 30 have a condition. 15 have condition X and 25 have condition Y. How many people have both X and Y?

I know the answer is 10 (thanks to the answers sheet) but why? When I simulate the question by giving random people X's and Y's, and count the people with both, I get answers ranging from 8 to 13. Is my simulation off? Is my thinking wrong?

Why would it be 10, all the time?

Only theory is 15+25=40, 40-30=10, but this doesn't seem logical. (25-15=10, but that's just coincidence right?)

Comment: In your simulation, you should check that the number of people you have assigned $X$ is actually 15, and those assigned $Y$ is actually 25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you are in a hall with two doors marked $X$ and $Y$. You have $40$  people in front of you. Ten of these don't have a condition so ask them to leave.

Now ask all of the people with condition $X$ to go into room $X$. There are 15 people in there. There were 30 in front of you so now there are only 15.

But 25 people have condition $Y$ so ten of these must already be in room $X$; so ten people have conditions $X$ and $Y$.

PS: Of course you can answer this using Venn Diagrams but I sometimes get frustrated with students who try to apply "mathematical methods" to a problem which they could probably do were it not posed as a maths problem but rather a riddle in a newspaper or TV show.

Answer (score 4):

Use the law $n(X \cup Y)=n(X)+n(Y)-n(X \cap Y),$ where $n(A)$ means the number of elements in set $A$. In your case, you know $n(X \cup Y)$ and also know $n(X),n(Y).$

EDIT: Note that the 40 in "Of 40 people..." has no effect. The same answer of 10 would result if this phrase were replaced by "Of 1000 people." Only the people having a condition can count toward those having both conditions X and Y.

Answer (score 1):

There are only 30 people with the condition.

Hence, of the 15 people with `X` only 5 have specific condition `X`. Others share it with condition `Y`.

This is because condition `Y` is related to 25 people of the 30. Hence, only 5 of those are left out with condition X. But total people with X were 15.

Hence, you get the answer as 10.

Answer (score 0):

On second thoughts, there's an easier way. 30 people have either X or Y. 15 people have X. So of the 30 people, 30 - 15 people don't have X (which means they have only Y). Similarly, of the 30 people, 30 - 25 people don't have Y(which means they have only X). So number of people with only X or only Y = 15 + 5 = 20.
So people with both X and Y = 30 - 20 = 10.

Answer (score -1):

I misunderstood the question earlier. By condition you mean symptom - which means that there could be people with a disease who don't have either symptom X or Y. I am posting a new answer:

Total no. of people = 40 = number of people with only symptom X + Number of people with only symptom Y + number of people with both symptom X and Y + number of people with neither symptom X or Y.

number of people with neither symptom X or Y = total population - people with either symptom = 40 - 30 = 10

Number of people without symptom X = total population - people with symptom X = 40 - 15 = 25

number of people with only symptom Y = people without symptom X - people with neither symptom = 25 - 10 = 15

number of people without symptom Y = total population - people with symptom Y = 40 -25 = 15

number of people with only symptom X = people without symptom Y - people with neither symptom = 15 - 10 = 5

therefore total number of people with only X or only Y symptom  = 15 + 5 = 20

therefore total number of people with both X and Y = Total number of people with either symptom X or Y - total number of people with only X or only Y symptom = 30 - 20 = 10

Comment: -1 What if there are 40 people with a disease...

Comment: Didn't understand your comment.Could you elaborate?It's given in  the question that (15 + 25 = 40) people have a condition.The statement 30 people have a condition doesn't make sense (or is it 30 people don't have a condition)?

Comment: By condition are you referring to symptom?Ok, then I understand.

Comment: Sorry when I say disease I mean condition. Do you see how your solution is wrong? The question says that 30 people have a condition not 40. If 40 have a condition out of forty people then none have both: 15 have $X$ and 25 have $Y$.

Comment: That's wrong. 15 have X doesn't mean that all 15 don't have Y.

Comment: This is still wrong. How do you have:

number of people with only symptom Y = 25 - 10 = 15 AND Number of people with only symptom Y = 15 - 10 = 5

Comment: Sorry that should be only symptom X int he last lin e. I'm correcting But my soultion is correct. Just refresh the page again and check.

Comment: No it is still wrong. How do you justify 

number of people with only symptom Y = 25 - 10 = 15?

You are implicitly using the solution to find the solution. Even if your solution was correct it is much more complicated than needs be.

Comment: Its not complicated. I've just elaborated. Yo've done the same thing using different terminology(rooms etc). Just compare.

Comment: As for your question, no. of people without Y is 40 - 25 =15.Have you understood this part ? Then you'll follow the rest. If not, let me know I'll elaborate my solution as a separate answer.

Comment: Yes I know that. 

I ask again explain why "no. of people with only symptom Y = 25 - 10 = 15". Specifically, why did you take away ten from 25?

PS: Elaborated is close to complicated in meaning :-)

Comment: Elaborate does not mean complicated(even closely) - it means easy to understand. An easy to present solution need not be easy to understand. I'll post my explanation as a separate answer - all the steps. Please check in after a couple of hours. I am busy with something else. Anyway nice talking to you.

Comment: There is a reason that your answer is downvoted twice. I don't know why you feel the need to change your answer in a few hours: there are at least two nice and correct answers above.
PS: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/elaborate, http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/elaborate?showCookiePolicy=true

Comment: Ok I've edited my answer.Compressed some of the steps into fewer steps.PS: look at the verb part of the meaning.

Comment: O.K. This works. I will remove my downvote but I still think your solution is very... convoluted in comparison to the slick answers of coffeemath and Back in a Flash.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But anyway, thanks for removing the downvote.I am also posting a new solution.